# hi-lock broken in js2-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

This has bothered me for a while.  I use `hi-lock' or more specifically [highlight-symbol](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/).  However, the highlighting does not work in js2-mode.

Wonder if anyone has a quick win before I dig too deeply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved:

```
(eval-after-load "hi-lock"
  '(defadvice hi-lock-set-pattern (around js2-hack activate compile)
     "js2 sets `font-lock-fontified' to t but doesn't really use the font-lock mechanism "
     (if (eq major-mode 'js2-mode)
         (let ((font-lock-fontified nil))
           ad-do-it)
       ad-do-it)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This may also help: http://mihai.bazon.net/projects/editing-javascript-with-emacs-js2-mode/js2-highlight-vars-mode

It's smarter and understands the scope of variables and has basic refactoring built in too (i.e. you can rename all the occurrences of a variable with M-r)